# Pyinstaller erro no executável não acha icones e imagens

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Fiz um app usando Tkinter e consigo gerar um executável dele com o PyIntaller, porém o app não abre e diz que não acha ícones e imagens que adicionei no Tkinter, o arquivo **.py** do app funciona de boa com seus ícones e imagens.
**EDITADO COMO RESPOSTA**
Resolvi em parte o problema exposto acima, não é um problema do pyinstaller em sí.
Colocando na imagem o caminho completo até o executável usando por exemplo:
 **icon_clear = PhotoImage(file=f"{os.getcwd()}\clear.png")**
Os arquivos de imagem precisarão estar sempre no mesmo caminho de onde o executável é chamado o que não é legal.
Se eu não colocar nenhum caminho e associar só o nome da imagem assim:
 **icon_clear = PhotoImage(file="clear.png")**
Não funcionará, pois não acha os arquivos mesmo estando todos no mesmo diretório do executável.

A nova pergunta seria:

Tem como usar arquivos de imagens e ícones no Tkinter, mas de forma que ao gerar o executável esses arquivos estejam incorporados ou então pelo menos dentro de alguma dll ?

Comment: vc esta colocando o -w do pyinstaller? e o nome do icone é esse mesmo? quando vou criar .exe eu ponho na pasta do jupyter e dou pyintaller --onefile projetos_jupyter/script.py

Comment: Sim, usei a seguinte linha: pyinstaller --onefile -w --i=youtube.ico main.py, Mas eu não sei dizer faz alguma diferença ao colocar na pasta do Jupyter, no meu caso, eu trabalho com venv(virtualenv) e dentro dela só tenho o necessário a este projeto, mas se eu compilar o executável sem nenhuma imagem e ícone o executável funciona de boa, só dá problema se eu inserir novamente as imagens e o ícone, quando executo main.py, tudo funciona, se converto para exe nada funciona.

Comment: entendi, nunca usei ícones em exe, achei isso na documentação:  `-i <FILE.ico or FILE.exe,ID or FILE.icns or "NONE">, --icon <FILE.ico or FILE.exe,ID or FILE.icns or "NONE">
FILE.ico: apply that icon to a Windows executable. FILE.exe,ID, extract the icon with ID from an exe. FILE.icns: apply the icon to the .app bundle on Mac OS X. Use “NONE” to not apply any icon, thereby making the OS to show some default (default: apply PyInstaller’s icon)`

Comment: acho q é erro de sintax, testa sem o = talvez

Comment: sem o sinal de igual não funciona, a sintaxe está correta, não sei se vc teve oportunidade de ver no post editado, mas coloquei lá um print de tela mostrando o ícone já compilado e aplicado ao executável, e logo abaixo a tela que é exibida mostrando o erro encontrado dizendo que não achou o caminho do arquivo .ico, e isso é surreal estar acontecendo, porque se vc põe um caminho completo, diz que não acha, e se vc não põe tb não acha....mas como eu citei antes, se eu remover do projeto os png e ico, deixar sem imagem alguma, a aplicação compila com o padrão do Tkinter(uma pena) e funciona.

Comment: NFO: Copying icons from ['youtube.ico'] 12500 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 20 bytes 12500 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 4264 bytes

Comment: achei q essa linha talvez ajude em algo. veja se algum dos icones pesa 20b ou 4kb, se sim sabemos que está sendo importado mas não usado. será q tem a ver com extensão do arquivo tenta .icns ou outra coisa

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291113/pyinstaller-setting-icons-dont-change tem mta informação importante aqui! ja viu?

Comment: sim, estou conseguindo gerar o executável com o arquivo de ícone (youtube.ico), o problema é que os demais ícones da aplicação em .png só funcionam se estiverem no mesmo diretório do executável....preciso saber agora como reunir tudo em um só arquivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embora eu tenha recebido aqui algumas dicas para tentar resolver o problema exposto, nenhuma delas foi **efetiva**, pois o problema ainda permanece o mesmo, mas encontrei um meio de resolver isso se considerar colocar todos os arquivos externos ao projeto, na mesma pasta em que está o executável.
Quando se compila um app Python usando o PyInstaller qualquer arquivo externo que for agregado ao projeto deve obrigatoriamente estar junto com o executável gerado dentro da pasta **dist** criada pelo PyInstaller, assim não haverá erros do tipo **no such file or directory**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
e o programa executável vai funcionar perfeitamente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém alerto que vai surgir um segundo problema, após gerar o executável com o PyInstaller, os programas de anti-vírus detectam o executável como sendo um Trojan(Falso positivo), analisado pelo site [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) e a tentativa de resolver esse problema foi descrita nos links que disponibilizo abaixo, porém e eu ainda não consegui resolver. Espero que quem ler isso consiga resolver e colabore deixando sua resposta e como foi resolvido.
Link1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg

e
Link2: https://github.com/google/spatial-media/issues/97

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Passei pelo mesmo problema (no Pyqt5) e eis como resolvi:

Explicação: o executável (inclusive o .qss) buscam dentro da pasta "dist", pois ali seria a nova "casa" do arquivo.

Para mim tem 2 soluções que funcionaram:

1 -  (mais cansado/urgente) - coloque todos os arquivos na pasta dist e crie um atalho pro Desktop e seja feliz.

2 - (Menos cansado/elegante) - modifique o .PY para que ele volte uma pasta buscando os arquivos aonde "estarão!", ou seja:

Aonde seria:

```
self.btnLogo.setStyleSheet('QPushButton { border-image: url("Imagem.ico") }')
```

coloca:

```
self.btnLogo.setStyleSheet('QPushButton { border-image: url("../Imagem.ico") }')
```

bom, funcionou aqui e espero de coração que te ajude aí!

Answer (score -1):

Para o pyinstaller reconhecer seu arquivo deve estar no formato .ico no caso do seu exemplo acima você esta usando o .png teria que converter ele ai na hora de gerar use o comando --icon=nomedoseuarquivo.ico

outra alternativa e usar o freeze pra gerar seu executável ele compila tudo oque você precisa junto com seu aplicativos levando todas as dlls necessárias.

Comment: no caso do pyinstaller sim, somente arquivo .ico, e, no caso do tkinter qualquer extenção inclusive ico, mas o que descobri é que tem que passar o caminho completo até o executável e estas imagens tem que estar na mesma pasta do executável....se eu tiver que distribuir isso, tenho que ficar enviando além do .exe, mandar um .ico e dois .png....kkkk é impraticável!...eu preciso ver uma forma de reunir isso tudo num só arquivo.